# HTML5 Video fire event on play (dim page)

Tags: javascript, css, html, events, video

when I use this schript:

```
<script>
myVid=document.getElementById("video1");
myVid.oncanplay=alert("Can start playing video");
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_canplay

a window pops up when video can play.

I would like to change the css from a div when the video starts playing (dim the background)
Can I get that work with the play event?

Regards

Torsten

Comment: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/ for examples of HTML5 video event binding + a bit of simple DOM manipulation (likely with jQuery) to change the CSS on your `<div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script will allow you to trigger an action on the Play event for your `<video>` element that (in this case) changes the background color of a `div`, but you could use the same method to adjust the class etc of one or more elements (or apply opacity to an intermediate layer).
The sample turns the event off so it's a one-shot thing, but adding events to trap play, pause, end, error etc you could get fairly granular control over the behavior.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body style="background-color: white"> 
<div id="dimMe" style="background-color:blue">
    <video id="video" autobuffer controls muted width=240 height=200>
        <source src="http://jcath-drg.s3.amazonaws.com/BigBuck.m4v">
        </source>
    </video>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener('play', dimBack, false);

function dimBack() {
    this.removeEventListener('play', dimBack, false);
    document.getElementById("dimMe").style.backgroundColor="green";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```